# Redux. Putting most of logic in ActionCreators for decreasing reducer overheads

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

Question about Redux data flow.

Let's talk about huge enterprice application. Dozens of modules, complex hierarchy of reducers, hundreds of action-types.
Simple flow:
Control dispatches an action(for example, input - typing). This action go through every reducer, go through hundreds of switch-cases, and new state is merged from all of reducers with minimal changes. I think, that we have huge unnecessary overhead in this scenario.

What options we can use to decrease overhead?

1. Use isolated high-level [sub-apps](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/IsolatingSubapps.html) with their own provider. 
   This option will decrease overheads. But if we need any common features in sub-apps, like account info/notifications/etc, we should duplicate it.
2. Use [asyncReducers](https://gist.github.com/gaearon/0a2213881b5d53973514) for code-splitting. 
   This option, also will decrease overheads, but it is not recommended.
3. Make a reducers with action-filters. In this case, we add additional information to each action, which reducer should process it.
   This option also decrease number of swithces and complexity of newState merging.
4. But in option 3 I can't understand one thing.

   - We have control, which is connected to concrete part of state.
   - 99% of actions are processed by single reducer.
   - Each action at reducer is processed by "case function", which is moved to separate logic-module.
   - We have action-creator which knows concrete reducer which process this action, and has access to global state.

Why action-creator should dispatch global action, which then will filtrated by cascade of reducers, and then will be swithed through dozens of cases, with not optimal merging of new global state?
Why can't we call case-function in action-creator, compute new global state in optimal way and dispatch it as payload with "SET_GLOBAL_STATE" action type?

I understand that it is anti-pattern. But i can't understand what we lose in this case. 
I'll be glad, if someone will explain me what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Several thoughts here.

First, per the [Redux FAQ entry on splitting logic between action creators and reducers](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/CodeStructure.html#structure-business-logic), it's up to you where to put the bulk of your logic.  If you prefer to do the actual calculations for what a piece of the new state should be in an action creator, and just have a given slice reducer do `return {...state, ...action.payload}`, you can.

Second, per the [Redux FAQ entry on the performance of calling reducer functions](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/Performance.html#performance-all-reducers), the cost of calling many reducer functions will generally be very minimal, since most of them will just check the action type and return their existing slice of state.  So, the reducer logic will rarely be a performance bottleneck.

Third: yes, it's entirely possible to calculate the *entire* new app state in an action creator, and have a single generic `"SET_GLOBAL_STATE"` action.  This will allow use of Redux's middleware and time travel debugging, etc.  However, this also throws away many of the possible benefits and use cases for Redux.  I discussed a lot of the intended purpose for Redux in my blog posts [The Tao of Redux, Part 1 - Implementation and Intent](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/05/idiomatic-redux-tao-of-redux-part-1/) and [The Tao of Redux, Part 2 - Practice and Philosophy](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/05/idiomatic-redux-tao-of-redux-part-2/).

To summarize the reasons why we discourage the idea your describing: Redux is intended to make it easy to trace *when*, *why*, and *how* a certain piece of state was updated.  While it's up to you to decide how granular you want your actions to be, ideally they should be semantically meaningful.  That way, when you read the action history log, you can actually understand the sequence of actions that were dispatched.  Also, if you search for a given action type, you should be able to quickly narrow down exactly where in the codebase that action is used.  If you only have a single `"SET_GLOBAL_STATE"` action, it will be almost impossible to determine what part of the code caused a given state update.